# Stack submatrices 3d matrix in one matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

So lets say that I have a 3d matrix `A` of variable size. Is there an easy to use command that stacks the matrix like `B = [squeeze(A(1,:,:)); squeeze(A(2,:,:)); ...; squeeze(A(n,:,:))]` ?

Right now I use the following, but its cumbersome:

```
if(length(A(:,1,1))==1)
    B =squeeze(A);
else
    B = zeros(length(A(:,1,1)*length(A(1,:,1)), length(A(1,1,:)));
    B(1:length(A(1,:,1)),:) = squeeze(A(1,:,:));

    for i=2:length(A(1,:,1)
        B(1:i*length(A(1,:,1)),:)=...
            vertcat(B, squeeze(A(i,:,:)));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do the same as `B = [squeeze(A(1,:,:)); squeeze(A(2,:,:)); ...; squeeze(n,:,:))]`. Not sure it's faster than the loop:

```
B = num2cell(A, [2 3]); % split along first dimension into cells 
B = permute([B{:}], [2 3 1]); % concatenate the cells along second dimension
    % and remove first dimension, which is a singleton
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) with a [permutation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) of the matrix's dimensions and a transpose:

```
C = reshape(permute(A,[3,2,1]),size(A,3),[]).';
```

Which will gracefully adapt to arbitrary row count.  A little test:

```
A = rand([3,4,4]);
B = [squeeze(A(1,:,:)); squeeze(A(2,:,:)); squeeze(A(3,:,:))];
C = reshape(permute(A,[3,2,1]),size(A,3),[]).';
all(B(:)==C(:)) % should be true/1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one more using [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
B = reshape(permute(A,[2,1,3]),[],size(A,3))
```

Comment: Crap, I knew that transpose wasn't needed. Well-done.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Yeah! At least you could use `[]` to replace that `size(A,1)*size(A,2)` to  make it look less cumbersome in  your solution, as OP hinted at it!

Comment: Yeah.  That's just a mental block I have as I use the single array convention versus the multiple input version.  I think I'll make that change now.